# Cloud Run as a proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Cloud Run as a proxy.

I am using NGINX image as a reverse proxy for my Kubernetes Services. Previously I was hitting my External Load Balancer IP. Now I want to hit my Internal Load Balancer IP with the same. I have created an Internal Load Balancer and set up my serverless VPC but while trying running my Cloud Run it is giving me 501 error.

My configuration for Docker file is below:

```
              server {

            listen 80;

             location / {

                proxy_pass [InternalIp];

                   }
                 }
```

nginx.conf file
FROM nginx

```
                  COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

my Dockerfile.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Error 501 means `Not Implemented`. The default listening port for Cloud Run is 8080. Show your deployment command and configuration files.

Comment: Yes it is resolved now, i didn't specify port no. in my nginx conf. "Internalip:portno"